# Codeigniter-dependent dropdown with ajax and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

I have 2 tables in my database: `Departments` and `Services`.

Each department has many services so when I select a department from the first dropdown I want my second dropdown to be populated with the corresponding services.

The problem is that when I click on a department from the list I get this in the 
console:

> POST http://localhost/ci/control_form/get_services/24 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

I was thinking that there may be a problem with the post_url that I am providing so how should I write it so that I won't get that error ?

Also,my response array with the services isn't being sent to the view anywhere, so how could I do this?Is this necessary?

I have this code in my view test_form.php

```
<?php echo form_open('control_form/add_all'); ?>
<label for="f_dep">Departament<span class="red">*</span></label> // first dropdown
    <select id="f_dep" name="f_dep">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        foreach($deps as $d){
            echo '<option value="' . $d->id_departament . '">' . $d->Nume_dep . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
<label for="f_serviciu">Serviciu<span class="red">*</span></label>  //second dropdown
    <select id="f_serviciu" name="f_serviciu" id="f_serviciu_label"> 
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
```

This is the Jquery function:

```
$('#f_serviciu, #f_serviciu_label').hide();
$('#f_dep').change(function(){
var departament_id = $('#f_dep').val();
if (departament_id != ""){
    var post_url =  "<?= base_url() ?>control_form/get_services/" + departament_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: post_url,
         success: function(servicii) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
          {
            $('#f_serviciu').empty();
            $('#f_serviciu, #f_serviciu_label').show();
               $.each(servicii,function(id,serviciu) 
               {
                var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option for each group
                  opt.val(id);
                  opt.text(serviciu);
                  $('#f_serviciu').append(opt); 
            });
           } //end success
     }); //end AJAX
} else {
    $('#f_serviciu').empty();
    $('#f_serviciu, #f_serviciu_label').hide();
}//end if
}); //end change
```

Here is the get_services function in my controller(control_form.php):

```
    function get_services($departament){
    $this->load->model('Model_form','', TRUE);    
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = $this->Model_form->get_servicii_by_departament($departament);
            echo(json_encode($data));
}
```

My control_form.php has the following methods:

```
public function index() {
    $data['deps'] = $this->model_departament->get_all_departments(); 
    $this->load->view('test_form', $data);
}

function add_all(){
    #Validate entry form information
    $msg="";
    $this->load->model('Model_form','', TRUE);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_dep', 'Departament', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_serviciu', 'Serviciu', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {        
        $msg = "error";
        echo $msg;
    }
    else {      
        $this->load->view('successful_employee');
    }
} 

function get_services($departament){
    $this->load->model('Model_form','', TRUE);    
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = $this->Model_form->get_servicii_by_departament($departament);
        echo(json_encode($data));
}
```

Model_form.php :

```
 function get_departament(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id_departament, Nume_dep FROM departament');
    return $query->result();
}

function get_servicii_by_departament ($departament){
    $sql = 'select S.Nume_serviciu from serviciu S, departament D where 
    S.Id_dep=D.id_departament and D.id_departament ='. '$departament';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $servicii = array();
    if($query->result()){
        foreach ($query->result() as $serviciu) {
            $servicii[$serviciu->Id_serviciu] = $serviciu->Nume_serviciu;
        }
        return $servicii;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your PHP error logs,check whether any error in your model.

Comment: there aren't any errors

Comment: Since it is gving you a 500, there is an error in the `control_form` controller or in all dependent models. Check that and post the updated info in the question

Comment: @blgBoy I added the code for the controller and the model. I don't really know how I should check for errors.I was thinking that maybe the response array with the services isn't being sent to the view.